# Time Complexity and Space complexity of a program (python)

Tags: python, string, list, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have written a python program to Calculate the average word length and return the average word length.

```
def stringlength(A: List[str]) -> int:
    average = sum(len(word) for word in A)/len(A)
    return average
```

test_list = ['gfg', 'is', 'best', 'for', 'geeks']

print(stringlength(test_list))

Answer: 3.4

I am new to calculating time and space complexitities.
I am assuming the time complexity of this python program would be O(N) where N is the length of the list since it uses builtin function like len and for loop
and space complexity would be O(N) since len() in for loop would return a list of lengths.
Can anyone please clarify if my assumption is correct

Comment: Complexity would be O(n) because you're iterating over full list ```len(word) for word in A```

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Time complexity would be O(n) where n is length of your list.

This is because you are going over every element in your list.

Comment: Thank you, what would be the space complexity of this program?

Comment: This is correct but only under the assumtion that `len(word)`s time complexity is O(1). I would rather vote for O(n) where n = `sum(len(word) for word in A)`.